# R:fit dynamic number of explanatory variable into polynomial regression

Tags: r

Suppose I was given an data frame `df` on runtime, how do I fit a polynomial model using polynomial regression, with each predictor is a column from df and has a degree of a constant k >= 2

The difficulty is, 'df' is read during runtime so the number and names of its columns are unknown when the script is written.(but I do know the response variable is the 1st column) So when I call `lm` I do not know how to write the `formula`.

In case of k = 1, then I can simply write a generic linear formula

```
names(df)[1] <- "y"
lm(y ~ ., data = df)
```

is there something similar I can do for polynomial formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One rather convoluted way is to create a `formula` for the `lm` regression call by pasting the terms together.

```
# some data
dat <- data.frame(replicate(10, rnorm(20)))

# Create formula - apply f function to all columns names excluding the first
form <- formula(paste(names(dat)[1], " ~ ",
                  paste0("poly(", names(dat)[-1], ", 2)", collapse="+")))
# run regression
lm(form , data=dat)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know formula can be characters. I thought they can only be literals.

Comment: Thanks for the formula tip. I used this variant: 
form <- formula(paste(names(dat)[1], " ~ ", paste("poly(", paste(names(dat)[2:n], collapse=" , "), ", degree=3)", collapse=" ")))  where n-1 is the number of features